What's the syntax to force LinkedIn job searches to look in the body of the postings?
I know that it's possible to force search to look in the posting body, because I had a search and alert set up that did it. But today I removed the existing alert while trying to refine it and I can't reproduce the results anymore.
Background: I have a long history with a technology that's tough to search for because it shares a name with an unrelated programming language, and very rarely shows up in the title for a position. After several months of occasional attempts to find related postings on LinkedIn and getting nothing useful back, I finally started getting good results last week with a search of the form <technology> <qualifier> and set up an alert for it. The resulting postings all included some form of <technology> <qualifier> in the job description body only. But I don't remember doing anything special to force that behavior, at the time it just...started working the way I wanted it to. Nothing in the GUI and nothing in the search docs I've found on LinkedIn mentions this as an option.
Then today I unthinkingly deleted that alert, and now searches using the same parameters are returning the same irrelevant results I was getting before I "lucked onto" the good results last week. None of the jobs I got email alerts for over the last week show up at all when I use the same search parameters today, even though most of them are still open. The "See All Jobs" links in the alert emails generate a "There was a problem loading your filters" error on the search page.
Is there a way to tell LinkedIn I want my job search results to match inside the posting's body? Or was getting the behavior I wanted just a weird fluke I'm not going to be able to reproduce?
